# GPUImage: Any way to cancel a [GPUImageMovie startProcessing] that is processing?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm referring the iOS framework [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/) there.

I need to know is there any way to cancel a `[GPUImageMovie startProcessing]` that is processing?

The scenario is when I choose to use another filter while there is one filter processing, I need to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `endProcessing`

```
GPUImageMovie *imageMovie = ...
[imageMovie endProcessing];
```

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageMovie.h

Comment: It seems that this is an internal method. I add a flag sentCancelMessage property and a method cancelProcessing to update it to YES. In the processing related method, check this flag first.

Answer (score 0):

I added a flag sentCancelMessage property and a method cancelProcessing to update it to YES. In the processing related method, check this flag first. still need to understand more of the framework so that the flag is checked in proper position.